Navbar menu-icon and menu-items not behaving as expected
The menu Item should be hidden for default larger screens as for my stylesheet, and the menu-icon should be clickable as for my . The output should be a Menu Icon appearing in smaller screens 800px below then shows Menu items when clicked.
Here are the relevant codes:
html:
<div class="navbar">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="images/New Project.png" alt="" width="125px">
                </div>
                <nav class="nav" id="MenuItems">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <img src="images/cart.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="">
                <img src="images/menu.png" class="menu-icon" onclick="menutoggle()">
            </div>

js:
 <!-- js for toggle menu -->

    <script>
        var MenuItems = document.getElementById("MenuItems");

        MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";

        function menutoggle()
        {
            if(MenuItems.style.maxHeight == "0px")
                {
                    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "200px"      
                }
            else
                {
                    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px" 
                }
        }
    </script>

css:
.menu-icon{
    width: 28px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}

/* Navbar for smaller screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
    nav ul{
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 0;
        background: #333;
        width: 100px;
    }

    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        margin-right: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    nav ul li a{
        color: #fff;
    }

    .menu-icon{
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

}

I am having trouble debugging my code, I cannot find and Identify if it's my script or style.css that causes the issue.
Here are the full codes in case someone need it.
index.html
style.css
The navbar should appear with a menu icon that is clickable and shows the contents (menu-items)
but I can't seem to find the issue because of my spaghetti code, I am sorry.

Thanks for the effort guys I appreciate it, but I still can't find the issue which is first then find the solution, something is messing up my navbar it either hides the lists or just do nothing if it works (the transition effects) if I make it responsive. Look:
https://streamable.com/7ec7af
https://streamable.com/pbmcw9
https://streamable.com/niin97
html and css pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/FFFyJyht
https://pastebin.com/wysMPP2j
whole source code:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ivpWJlUT1MSF3xXruUbg9uDOTYWo4Iz5?usp=sharing

Here is code simplified


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var MenuItems = document.getElementById("MenuItems");
    
    // Initial state
    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";
    MenuItems.style.display = "none"; // Hide content that exceeds max-height

    function menutoggle() {    
        if (MenuItems.style.maxHeight === "0px") {
            MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "200px";
            MenuItems.style.display = "flex";
            // Adjust as needed
        } else {
            MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";
            MenuItems.style.display = "none";
            
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("toggle-button").addEventListener('click', menutoggle);
});
.menu-icon{
    width: 28px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}


/* Navbar for smaller screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
    nav ul{
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 0;
        background: #333;
        width: 100px;
    }

    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        margin-right: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    

    nav ul li a{
        color: #fff;
    }

    .menu-icon{
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
     <div class="navbar">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="images/New Project.png" alt="" width="125px">
                </div>
                <nav class="nav" id="MenuItems">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <img src="images/cart.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="cart">
                <button id="toggle-button" ><img src="images/menu.png" alt="menu" class="menu-icon" ></button>
            </div>
     
  </body>
</html>



Here just trigger your functions in js by id rather than passing it directly.

it does actually show the actual lists but the cart is moving when I clicked it, I also added some transition under nav ul{overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.5s;} but it does nothing. look here https://streamable.com/niin97
https://streamable.com/pbmcw9
